# Find index of vector element using search_n function

Tags: c++, stdvector

I need to find index of vector element using a function from algorithm library.

EXAMPLE:

{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Element 5 found at 5 position.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
bool comp(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
int main() {
  int n = 10;
  std::vector<int> a{10, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9};
  sort(a.begin(), a.begin() + n, comp);
  int number = 5;
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;
  it = std::search_n(a.begin(), a.begin() + n, number);
  if (it != a.end())
    std::cout << "found at position " << (it - a.begin()) << '\n';
  else
    std::cout << "match not found\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I get error (in the 11th line):

> no matching function for call to ‘search_n(std::vector::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, int&)’

Could you explain me what is the problem here?

Comment: Which overload of [`std::search_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n) are you intending to call? Your arguments match *none* of them (minimal arguments is 4 and you're only providing 3). If you're looking for *one* element you should be using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), not `std::search_n` (or, I suppose you could just supply a count of `1`).

Comment: I need search_n just for one vector, so that would be 3 arguments a.begin(), a.begin()+n, number

Comment: Maybe I didn't make that clear. `search_n` has **no** overloads that take three arguments. Period. That function is designed to look over an iterator range (supplied by the first two arguments, for `count` (supplied by the third argument) consecutive instances of a specific value (supplied by the fourth argument). Read the documentation I linked.

Comment: I cannot use loops for this, only fuctions from algorithm library

Comment: Um... what ???? Who said anything about loops?

Comment: is there a way to use `find` function to find index of found element without using loops?

Comment: *Read the documentation I linked*. If you changed `search_n` in your posted code to `find` it would very likely do *exactly* what you want.

Comment: well with find function I can find pointer to number, and after that I could go through loop and save index of that found pointer, but is there a way to do that without loops?

Comment: Do what I said, and don't write any loops? As I said, your already-provided code, substituting `std::find` for `std::search_n`, will do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::search_n` function looks for a **sequence** of a specified number of occurrences of a particular value in a range; that number is the third argument (`count` on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n)).

So, if you *insist* on using `std::search_n` for this, you will need to add an extra argument (`count`, which will be `1`) in your call:

```cpp
it = std::search_n(a.begin(), a.begin() + n, 1, number);
```

However, using `search_n` is something of an overkill when looking for a single value; better to use the simpler (and faster) [`std::find` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Also, in place of `a.begin() + n`, you can use the easier and clearer `a.end()`.

```cpp
it = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), number);
```

Also note that indexes and iterator positions in C++ start at **zero**, so, with the above fix(es) applied to your code, the answer will be "found at position 4"; if you want a 1-based position, then add `1` to the position; something like this:

```cpp
auto position = std::distance(a.begin(), it) + 1;
```